# Generate multiple Textbox dynamically on button click in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to generate multiple text boxes on button click by user if required to enter multiple values.
For eg: a person may have more than two qualification degrees. One text box is visible at runtime, now if he want to enter multiple value he may click add button and another text box appears bound with same data table.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple...Just create the Texbox object and add the control to your div as like below example....Make sure that your adding control id is unique.....

```
HtmlGenericControl dynDivtxtBx = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
dynDivtxtBx.Attributes.Add("class", "divClass");

TextBox txtDegree = new TextBox();
txtDegree.ID = "txtDegree1";
txtDegree.MaxLength = 50;
dynDivtxtBx.Controls.Add(txtDegree);
```

Comment: have one hidden control and store the count value....initially, it should be 1 and while adding new control read the hidden control value and add 1 to the existing value. So second time it will be 2 and update the hidden value...so on..